# Android - How to add footer from xml layout to a custom activity to display it in all activities?

Tags: android

I want to create a custom activity to display a footer to all activities that extend it.
I have created an XML layout called footer.xml
How could I add it to this custom activity ?

```
public class CustomActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //what should I do to add footer there ?
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you use fragments instead?

Answer (score 1):

include your `footer.xml` in other `activities` above other items in `layout`. or create main `Activity`, which will hold `footer.xml` and `View`, where would be added `Fragments` (replace `activities` with `Fragments`)

Answer (score 0):

Use following in all your activity layout screen

```
<include layout="@layout/footer"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a footer xml and use something like

```
<include layout="@layout/footer" />
```

Or use a main layout with a footer and FrameLayouts or something like that ;)